# Cancel Segue and show alert - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I got the tutorial from this site: http://jamesleist.com/ios-swift-tutorial-stop-segue-show-alert-text-box-empty/

This is my current code. It's just not working, which causes the app to crash because if any of the fields are empty, the next ViewController crashes.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Darwin

class View3on3 : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var APTeams: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APRounds: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APBreakers: UITextField!

var AP1: String = String()
var AP2: String = String()
var AP3: String = String()


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeTextFields()
}


func initializeTextFields()
{
    APTeams.delegate = self
    APTeams.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APRounds.delegate = self
    APRounds.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APBreakers.delegate = self
    APBreakers.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}



@IBAction func userTappedBackground(sender: AnyObject)
{
    view.endEditing(true)
}

override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, sender: AnyObject!) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "segueTest" {

        if (APTeams.text!.isEmpty) {

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "No Text"
            alert.message = "Please Enter Text In The Box"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()

            return false
        }

        else {
            return true
        }
    }

    // by default, transition
    return true

}


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "segueTest"){

            var passs = segue.destinationViewController as! View3on3Results

                passs.AP1 = APTeams.text!
                passs.AP2 = APRounds.text!
                passs.AP3 = APBreakers.text!
        }


}
}
```

I tried looking at other questions on SO, but the solutions all threw errors. I think this is due to Swift updating to 2.0. I could be wrong- very new to this.

Comment: Crashing occurs after segue or before segue?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon After I try to segue.

Comment: may be because you are only checking `APTeams.text!.isEmpty` in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` but not the other 2 fields `APRounds` and `APBreakers` for empty?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr when I tried to segue, I filled in the other two fields and only left APTeams empty.

Comment: what is the crash log says?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr That it failed trying to unwrap a nil value. Which is logically what would happen if the stop segue didn't work, because then nothing would be sent to the next view

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may be because of AlertView. In swift 2.0 UIAlertView is replaced by UIAlertController:

```
let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

alertController.addAction(okAction)

presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Replace your UIAlertView with UIAlertViewController using the above code.

Edited:

Also make the IBOutlet optionals:

```
@IBOutlet weak var APTeams: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var APRounds: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var APBreakers: UITextField?
```

Comment: Still throws this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: @SohilRMemon Nope, same error. It's not cancelling the segue. Is there something wrong with the way I've structured my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call `segue` manually using `performSegueWithIdentifier`
 if the `textfield` is not `empty` and if it is then show `alert`

Your code might look like [may be on button click when you are submitting your data or trying to segue **Or** put this code inside `viewDidLoad` after `initializeTextFields()`]

```
if(APTeams.text!.isEmpty){
  // your code for showing alert. You can use UIAlertController if UIAlertView is not working.
}
else
{
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueTest",sender: View3on3Results.self)

}
```

And you dont need `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I'm going to try this then show you my complete code if it goes wrong. @FrequencyMatched

Comment: Okay, the alert popped up, but it popped up the moment the view was opened as opposed to when I tried to segue. I think it was because of its placement inside viewDidLoad. Gonna try putting it outside now. @FrequencyMatched

Comment: All you want to do is to check textfield value and then decide whether to show alert or perform segue..right?

Comment: @TheveshTheva and yes..it is because it checked the value of textfield as view has been loaded and perform appropriate action specified in conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This was the code that worked. Thank you to @SohilRMemon and @FrequencyMatched for helping me put this together.

Code here:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Darwin

class View3on3 : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var APTeams: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APRounds: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var APBreakers: UITextField!

var AP1: String = String()
var AP2: String = String()
var AP3: String = String()


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initializeTextFields()
}


func initializeTextFields()
{
    APTeams.delegate = self
    APTeams.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APRounds.delegate = self
    APRounds.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    APBreakers.delegate = self
    APBreakers.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
}


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (APTeams.text!.isEmpty || APRounds.text!.isEmpty || APBreakers.text!.isEmpty)
        {

            let alertController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "Are you sure?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(okAction)

            presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        else
        {
            let DestViewController : View3on3Results = segue.destinationViewController as! View3on3Results

            DestViewController.AP1 = APTeams.text!
            DestViewController.AP2 = APRounds.text!
            DestViewController.AP3 = APBreakers.text!

            //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueTest",sender: View3on3Results.self)//
        }



        }

}
```